# Import SASS file from database instead of filesystem

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I don't have much experience with Ruby. I want to @import sass from database instead of filesystem. I did not find any examples online. How should I go about implementing this. I see that I have to extend an importer class but since I have no understanding of ruby I need to know where in my filesystem does this class reside (Just to check it out) and in general what are the basic steps involved.

More information

MySQL database contains sass content.
So in my web application I accept sass (as string) from user which may contain an import statement for example :

```
@import test.scss
body  { color:red }
```

Now in my MySQL DB I will have something like this

```
Table  sass_files
column_name             filename  |   content
example row             test.scss |   p {color:blue;}
```

I want to make this import work, sure I can just do a regular expression match to get the filename from the user input and then query the DB by that file name and get the content.
But I read that there is a nice way to make ruby/sass use DB as a load-path instead of filesystem.

UPDATE

SO i created a dummy custom importer class with find method as

```
def find(name, options)
  Sass::Engine.new("p { color :blue; }", options)
end
```

How do i add this importer to sass load paths w/o using ruby, like can i make change to the source files in the sass gem folder and add this importer to lib/sass/importers?

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using? What kind of file is it? I'm not sure if the question is clear. Considering adding more details, examples and pseudocode to better clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Compass to compile, you can add a custom Sass importers in the Compass config file. For example, compiling using `compass compile -c config.rb`, you would include something like this in your `config.rb` file:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'importer.rb')
Sass.load_paths << Sass::Importers::Custom.new()
```

Then in `importer.rb` in the same directory, you would include your importer definition:

```
module Sass
    module Importers
        class Custom < Base
            def find(name, options)
                if name == '[globals]'
                    options[:syntax] = :scss
                    options[:filename] = 'globals'
                    options[:importer] = self
                    return Sass::Engine.new("$imported-variable: blue;", options)
                else
                    return nil
                end
            end

            def find_relative(uri, base, options)
                nil
            end

            def key(uri, options)
                [self.class.name + ":" + uri, uri]
            end

            def mtime(uri, options)
                nil
            end

            def to_s
                '[custom]'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then in your Sass file you can use the importer:

```css
@import '[globals]';
p {
    color: $imported-variable;
}
```

Of course, this is just a dummy implementation that only accepts a URI matching `"[globals]"`. You'll need to supply your own implementation that accesses your MySQL database, as I don't have any experience with database access in Ruby. Hopefully this should get you a little closer, though, in addition to the links that @Sean has provided.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, sass will only import local files (anything else is compiled into a CSS @import statement) but [as the sass docs explain](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#custom_importers) you can write your own custom importers by extending the [Sass::Importers::Base](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Importers/Base.html) class.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6861985/131226) to another question gives an example of a custom HTTP importer. You could approach this in (at least) two ways: write a custom importer for your database or serve the sass file over HTTP from the database (via a simple PHP page or something)

Comment: Yes I saw that, but where do i put those files in (the importer files), Do i need to put a require or add those importer files some where in sass source files?

Comment: You put your importer files wherever makes sense and add the path to the [load_paths option](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#load_paths-option). How you do that depends on how your app is configured and how you're using sass.

Comment: I thought the whole notion of building your own importer was so that its independent of your app. I just need a importer which imports from DB and there are no examples online. Since I don't program in Ruby I am having trouble getting started on how to do it.

Comment: It's somewhat independent of your app, but your app is dependent on sass. How is app using sass? Writing an importer is going to require knowledge of Ruby.

Comment: The app just runs a "compass compile" on a file created by the app from user input of sass string

Comment: If you can tell me which is the method in the importers:base class which takes the file name as parameter and looks for that in the filesytem, I should be able to extend that and hack it with my minimal knowledge of ruby.

Comment: Compass isn't really sass, as I understand it. It just also reads sass formated files. What I've been describing is how to extend a sass application. Having a custom importer for _Compass_ the way you're using it may or may not be possible.

Comment: Compass should be using the Sass importer behind the scenes. If not then I will do a sass compile.